# Accessing some of AVAudioEngine properties or methods causing a memory leak in Xcode Instruments

Tags: memory-leaks, avaudioengine, xcode-instruments

I'm not sure wether `AVAudioEngine` is internally causing some memory leaks or it is a bug of Xcode Instruments but I had a strange case where I was seeing memory leaks after launching the app.

Finally reduced the code to just calling `let node = AVAudioEngine().inputNode` in `AppDelegate`. Notice I'm even initialising it in place and accessing the input node. It should be created and deallocated immediately after `didFinishLaunching` scope ends. When I run instruments I keep getting this memory leak for some reason.[image: Leak in XCode Instruments]

It's really easy to reproduce just by writing this for example and running Xcode Instruments leak preset.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let node = AVAudioEngine().inputNode
    return true
}
```

Comment: Registered this bug report to Apple https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/12130885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple support has contacted me and it appeared to be an expected behavior.

> UISoundNewDevice is a global object that is not expected to be deallocated (as the function name suggests: immortal). Thus, this is a false alarm.